# Handle browser tab in angular 5

Tags: angular, browser, tabs

I have a situation but I have no solution to do that so hopefully, you guys can help me out.

1. I'm on the Dashboard page (tab 1), I negative to a new page on a new browser tab (tab 2).
2. On the new browser tab (tab 2), I do something then close it. After that, I want to re-active Dashboard page (tab 1) and reload it. How can I do?

Comment: You want to trigger a page load to a new url when a tab is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Are the dashboard and non-dashboard pages on the same origin? Then you could do an approach like this:

```
// constructor in a component belonging to the dashboard
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => { 
    if (!document.hidden) { 
      const nonDashBoardTabStatus: string = sessionStorage.getItem("nonDashBoardTabStatus");
      // do something with the retrieved information
    }
  }
);
```

And in the non-dashboard-components you do:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("nonDashBoardTabStatus", "SOME_STATUS");
```

Now you just have to take care of the fact that the existence of the non-dashboard-info is not guaranteed (sessionstorage might not be sharable betweent abs in some browsers or perhaps one tab is not finished writing before other gets active), so you might want to put a loop there fetching data and having a fallback.